# I cant use FullCalendar Jalali in GitHub

Tags: javascript, html, date, fullcalendar

Im new fullstack developer.I have a persian website about managing and scheduling my university.
I want to add a persian calender with Jalali with javascripts library.I searched and found FullCalendar libarary but the date is A.D

Full calendar GitHub page:
[text](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar)

Full calendar Jalali GitHub page:
[text](https://github.com/Natico/fullcalendar-Jalaali/)

I dont know how really using Full Calendar Jalali.
the instructions are not enough and im confusing.

I had download GitHub code and write this code but it doesn't work!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='fa'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link href='fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
    
    <script src='fullcalendar-Jalaali-master/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar-Jalaali-master/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar-Jalaali-master/lib/moment-jalaali.js'></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar-Jalaali-master/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar-Jalaali-master/lang/fa.js'></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar-Jalaali-master/fullcalendar-jalaali.js'></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
              isJalaali: true, // Enable Jalaali calendar
              isRTL: true, // Set right-to-left mode
              lang: 'fa', // Set language to Persian
              
              // Other FullCalendar options
              // You can add more configurations or callbacks here
          });
      });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you working entirely in the Jalaali calendar or just presenting dates using it? For presentation only you can use *Intl.DateTimeFormat* or *toLocaleString* with appropriate options, e.g. `new Date().toLocaleString('en-gb-u-ca-persian')` returns "02/10/1402 AP, 10:57:12" when `new Date()` returns "Sat Dec 23 2023 10:57:12", which is correct according to the converter [here](https://www.iranchamber.com/calendar/converter/iranian_calendar_converter.php).

Comment: Not working in what way exactly? Do you get an error? Or some specific unexpected behaviour? Please clarify. See also [ask]. Thanks

Comment: i mean not working is when i run the code with liveserver it doesnt show anything.

Comment: Ok. So did you do any debugging or investigation? Do you, for example, have any errors or problems mentioned in the browser's Console or Network tool? It doesn't sound like you have attempted to analyse the problem so far.